# 'No such file or directory' when trying to create file outside fo working directory

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I'm trying to create several files in my program using code similar to this:

```
  character(50) :: path='~/Documents/test/'
  character(20) :: folder='folder/'

  call system('mkdir ' //trim(path))
  call system('mkdir ' //trim(path)//trim(folder))

  open(1,file=trim(path)//trim(folder)//'file',status='unknown')
```

The program will create the directories, but then gives the run time error, Cannot open file '~/Documents/test/folder/file': No such file or directory

If I just make path='test' so the directory is created in the directory I'm running the program from, everything works fine.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You are likely running into a problem with expansion of the tilde into the home directory.  The string "mkdir ~/Documents/test/' that is passed to `system` works, because it is executed essentially as a shell command.  The string in your `open` statement isn't processed by the shell.

Comment: Yup that was it! Thank you!

Comment: I see, but what did y4u do to solve this issue?